# Writing a Java program that takes a file and reads the number of characters, lines, and words. It won't find the txt file when I run it

Tags: java

I created a txt file with random text that's inputted into my code below. When I type the file to run it (it is not hard coded), it continuously gives the error I have set. How can I fix this?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P7_5
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter file name: ");
    String fileName = input.next();

    File file = new File(fileName); //hard code file here
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {
        in = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File was not found!");
    }

    int numLines = 0;
    int numWords = 0;
    int numCharacters = 0;
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        String[] words = line.split("\\s+");

        numLines += 1;
        numCharacters += line.length();
        numWords = words.length;
    }

    in.close();

    System.out.printf("Number of lines are: \n", numLines);
    System.out.printf("Number of words are: \n", numWords);
    System.out.printf("Number of characters are: \n", numCharacters);
}
```

}

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: Also, i think this --> "numWords = words.length;" is meant to be --> "numWords += words.length;"

Comment: Error message when I run on Netbeans IDE: run:
Please enter file name: random.txt
File was not found!
Number of lines are: 
Number of words are: 
Number of characters are:

Comment: Please enter the absolute path of the file like`C:\\MyFolder\\otherFolder\\random.txt`

Comment: Is your text file in the same directory as your build?

Comment: txt file is located elsewhere (moved to Downloads). I got it to run without the error by using the full file path but the calculations are still blank.

Comment: Step through it using breakpoints to see whether `numLines` etc. is actually incremented.